# Removing Max Value

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am trying to remove the entry(s) with the max value to change a program's behavior.  I have tried LINQ, but get the following error:

> CS1936  C# Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'long'.  'Where' not found.

The error is on `stanDev` within `maxValue`.  How do I correct the error?
The code is:

```
if (DailyStandard.Count() > 10)
{
    var dailyAvg = DailyStandard.Average(f => f.functionTime);
    var standDev = StandardDeviation(DailyStandard.Select(x => x.functionTime).ToList());
    var maxValue = from item in standDev
                   where item.max()
                   select item;
    maxValue.Remove();
```

Comment: If `standDev` is a `long`, i.e. an integer, then it doesn't contain any items for you to iterate over. It sounds like you want to select from `DailyStandard` instead.

Comment: What data type is `standDev`?

Comment: This is why `var` sucks.  Only use it when the _type is obvious_

Comment: @fuglede I will implement the change tomorrow morning......Thank you all for your input.

Comment: @Amy I am not a huge fan of var, but have been using it lately.  Need to kick the habit.

Comment: @Pens_Cup87 `var` is fine when the data type involved is obvious from its usage.  In this case, `StandardDeviation` doesn't contain any indication of what it does or returns.  Ideally function names should contain a verb, e.g. `CalculateStandardDeviation`.  What data type is `standDev`?  Is it a single number?  Or a collection of numbers?

Comment: Always consider types. What type is `standDev`? Assuming it is `IEnumerable` What type is `item` then? Given that, does `max` apply? and what type does `where` expect and what type does `max` return?

Answer (score 3):

You could do :

```
DailyStandard = DailyStandard.OrderByDescending(f => f.functionTime).Skip(1).ToList();
```

`Skip(1)` will remove the first item of the collection, which has been ordered by functionTime descending. So it will remove the single item of DailyStandard that has the highest functionTime.

Comment: @J,Loscos  Your suggestion worked well.  Thank you all for your assistance.